# Obtain User's Documents folder in Python on Unix and Windows

Tags: python

I'm looking to obtain info on a user's document folder on all the major OSes:

```
Windows: C:\Users\<user>\Documents
MacOSX: /Users/<user>/Documents
Linux: /home/<user>/Documents
```

***Also, incase the user has manually shifted the location of Documents folder location, this should be handled as well.***

How do I do that?

I found some solutions online to handle Windows scenario. But nothing for the other operating systems.

Comment: Linux might not even *have* a Documents folder. Ubuntu and the more common distros will create one, sure, but it's not required by any means.

Comment: Linux doesn't really have a standard Documents folder, some OS variants add one though. If you want to know where the folder is and you aren't sure you should ask the user for clarification. Giving them a default based on their OS would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Unix-like systems don't necessarily have a Documents folder. That's a Windows convention that Mac and Ubuntu have adopted. Other Linuxes may not have such a folder. However, almost every system will have a user home directory.

On Unix-like systems, you can use `~` to get the user's home directory, or you can expand `$HOME` if you need the path as text. On Windows, you can expand the environment variable `%USERPROFILE%`. This will give you the equivalent of `/home/username` or `C:\Users\username\`.

Answer (score 0):

Linux distributions adhering to the freedesktop.org interoperability scheme have a `xdg-user-dir` command line tool, so you could do

```
import subprocess
try :
 documents_dir = subprocess.check_output(["xdg-user-dir", "DOCUMENTS"], universal_newlines=True).strip()
except :
 documents_dir = some_default_value
```

Answer (score 0):

another variant for Linux

```py
import os

config_file = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/user-dirs.dirs")
path = open(config_file, 'r').read()
paths = path.splitlines()
home_folder = os.path.expanduser("~")
d = {}

for p in paths:
    if "=" in p and "XDG_" in p and not "xxx" in p:
        line = p.split("=")
        key = line[0].split("_")[1].split("_")[0]
        name = line[1].lstrip('"').rstrip('"').replace("$HOME", home_folder)
        d[key] = name
        
for key, value in d.items() :
    print (f"{key}: {value}")
```